# Procedurally covering a surface with grass?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just built a vertex shader for my grass asset, and I want to make a whole field of swaying grass. I know it's possible, but I haven't found tutorial or forum thread that solves it yet. Can someone help me out?

Thank you a ton in advance.

Comment: Update, found out about gpu instancing, but still no success.

Comment: If you are using a unity terrain, you can do it like this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/terrain-Grass.html